# form validation using ajax doesn't return true

Tags: jquery, validation, return-value

i'm having a form validation to change the password the first field blur checks if the password is correct using ajax and other two fields to enter the new password and check if they match but it doesn't return true at all form doesn't submit though password is correct and other passwords match and i don't know where's the error here's the code
html :

```
<form id="pwd" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate();">
<table width="400" border="1">
<tr>
<td>current password</td>
<td><input type="password" class="user_text" name="old_pass" id="old_pass" onblur="check_oldpass();" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>new password</td>
<td><input type="password" class="user_text" name="new_pass1" id="new_pass1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>confirm password</td>
<td><input type="password" class="user_text" name="new_pass2" id="new_pass2" onblur="confirmpass();" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="update_pass" value="حفظ" id="update_pass" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

jquery code :

```
function check_oldpass(){
var oldpass = $("#old_pass").val();
var ajax = false;
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST","checkpass.php?pass="+oldpass);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
        var passresponse = ajax.responseText;
        if(passresponse.indexOf('wrong') !== -1){
            noty({
                layout: 'center',
                  theme: 'defaultTheme',
                  type: 'error',
                  text: 'password is not correct',
                  dismissQueue: true, // If you want to use queue feature set this true
                  template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span><div class="noty_close"></div></div>',
                  animation: {
                    open: {height: 'toggle'},
                    close: {height: 'toggle'},
                    easing: 'swing',
                    speed: 500 
                  },
                  timeout: 2000, 
                  force: false, 
                  modal: true,
                  closeWith: ['click'],
                  callback: {
                    onShow: function() {},
                    afterShow: function() {},
                    onClose: function() {},
                    afterClose: function() {}
                  }
                });

                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;    
            }

    }
}
ajax.send(null);

}

function confirmpass(){
var newpass1 = $("#new_pass1").val();
var newpass2 = $("#new_pass2").val();
if(newpass1 != newpass2){
            noty({
                layout: 'center',
                  theme: 'defaultTheme',
                  type: 'error',
                  text: 'passwords do not match',
                  dismissQueue: true, // If you want to use queue feature set this true
                  template: '<div class="noty_message"><span class="noty_text"></span><div class="noty_close"></div></div>',
                  animation: {
                    open: {height: 'toggle'},
                    close: {height: 'toggle'},
                    easing: 'swing',
                    speed: 500 
                  },
                  timeout: 2000, 
                  force: false,
                  modal: true,
                  closeWith: ['click'],
                  callback: {
                    onShow: function() {},
                    afterShow: function() {},
                    onClose: function() {},
                    afterClose: function() {}
                  }
                });
                return false;

}
else{
    return true;    
}

}


function validate() {
$.each($("form#pwd :input"),function(){
    $(this).blur(); 
});
if(!check_oldpass() || !confirmpass){
    return false;   
}
else{
    return true;    
}
}
```

Comment: goodness!! how about a working example, not many people are going to trouble shoot that!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used to much time for review the javascript code. Could be posible that you have been used an single quote for write don't in the text atribute passed to `noty` call (where is defined that function?) in `function confirmpass` ?

```
function confirmpass(){
var newpass1 = $("#new_pass1").val();
var newpass2 = $("#new_pass2").val();
if(newpass1 != newpass2){
            noty({
                layout: 'center',
                  theme: 'defaultTheme',
                  type: 'error',
                  text: 'passwords don't match',  <<----
```

Comment: i've removed apostrophe and still the same problem

Comment: You are doing a ajax call with method POST and passing the parameter `pass` in the URL. It's not the correct way.

Comment: You are using jQuery in your script. I can recomend to you for use the ajax facilities that there are in jQuery. As example of use: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)